# Fish autocomplete pager doesn't highlight options when tabbing through them

Tags: fish

Previously, fish would highlight the currently selected autocomplete. Now it doesn't. Do you know how to make it highlight it?

**Observed behavior**
[image: an example of me typing cd, then pressing tab, and all the options appear, but the currently autocompleted one isn't highlighted]

**Expected behavior**

[image: An example of someone using fish shell to highlight autocomplete answers successfully]

Comment: The version of fish you're using should be given. You also say "previously" but don't explain what that means. Did you upgrade the version of fish you're using? If so what was the previous version? Did you install some OMF plugins or otherwise modified your configuration? If so what did you do?

Comment: Just a friendly, neighborhood reminder that questions on this site should be about *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* The way this question is phrased, at least, it is about *configuration* and would likely be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com) or the [Unix & Linux Stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com). I would recommend either editing it to clarify if it really is a programming question or deleting it here and reposting it on the proper site. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selected background color is stored in $fish_pager_color_selected_background, or $fish_color_search_match if that isn't set.

It seems either these aren't set, or the value you chose looks like your terminal's background. Given that you now have a light background and fish has no way to detect it that's hard to avoid.

Use something like

```
set -g fish_pager_color_selected_background --background=533
```

to set it. The value should look like arguments to fish's [set_color](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/set_color.html) builtin.

See https://fishshell.com/docs/current/interactive.html#pager-color-variables for more information.

Comment: `set -g fish_pager_color_selected_background --background=cyan` worked for me!

Comment: Whoops, actually `set -Ux fish_pager_color_selected_background --background=cyan`, to ensure the color persists across terminal restarts